# AWS Pinpoint - Unregistered Application. Pinpoint is not registered in PNS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-amplify, aws-pinpoint

We have registered FCM server key on Pinpoint. We were able to successfully receive messages on our emulator when tested with Cloud Messaging on Firebase console. However, when we are trying to send push notification using GCM channel of 'sendUsersMessages' API - we receive below error for endpoint

```
"DeliveryStatus": "PERMANENT_FAILURE",
"StatusCode": 404,
"StatusMessage": "{\"errorMessage\":\"Unregistered Application\",\"channelType\":\"GCM\",\"pushProviderStatusCode\":\"0\",\"pushProviderError\":\"a153cc45babasomepinpointid67073b-gcm#Pinpoint is not registered in PNS.\"}"
```

What does this error mean? Does it mean our Pinpoint application is not registered on Firebase? Or our device doesn't have token? or something else. Couldn't find any answers. Please help

Answer (score 0):

After some play around - figured out that I was using *RestrictedPackageName* matching my application's FCM console package name (like *com.xyz.app.abc*) - I removed that and push notification went through successfully.

Comment: I'm running into a similar issue. What did you mean by using a RestrictedPackageName. I'm not using something like com.example but I'm running into the same issue.